# Email html template: Line break differs in Yahoo email clients

Tags: html, css, email-templates

I am creating HTML email template which should work in all email clients like Yahoo, Gmail, and outlook. When I validated my email content in Yahoo mail mobile web and Yahoo mail iOS app, line breaks are different even if style applied is same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

<style type="text/css">
* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table style="background:red;width:200px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" width="200" > 
    <tr> 
        <td  style="background:yellow;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;font-family:Arial;border:none;font-weight:normal;padding:0;margin:0;outline:none;box-shadow:none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.          
        </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I tried to normalize it applying possible CSS and given 200px width to the container. Still, line break differs. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It’s a different `font`. Nothing you can do.

Comment: Yes, definitely a font issue. The Yahoo iOS and web app are just using different fonts. Like AjAX mentioned, there is little you can do. However, consistency is important, also for html e-mails. If you work with html email alot there are API's out there that allow you generate responsive html e-mails without messing with tables and css youself. [Json2Email](https://json2email.com) is one but there are others as well.